# All the different ways to turn a TextView into a hyperlink?

Tags: android

Here are the different ways I have discovered so far:

Movement:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextBox);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(strText));
```

AutoLink:

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

Linkify:

```
Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.ALL);
```

1. Are there any other ways to create links?
2. Which method is best to use?

Comment: 1. A SpannableString with a ClickSpannable. 2. the one that suits you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these methods should be more than enough. If they can't solve a specific criteria you have, please elaborate in your question.

One more I can add is in **Strings.xml**:

```
<string name="example">Example link to email: <a href="mailto:example@links.com?Subject=Example" target="_top">example@links.com</a></string>
```

My preference is to use the **Autolink** method:

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

or

```
android:autoLink="email"
```

The reason I like this method is because of its flexibility and simplicity. You are telling android very specifically what kind of link you want this text to be, so it can be resolved correctly, e.g. opening Chrome browser, or Gmail etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply put your link in the `textview` and add:

```
<TextView
...
android:autoLink="web"/>
```

it will work. However, it will display the whole link. You can use this instead to refer to your link through a tag:

```
Text1.setText(
        Html.fromHtml(
            "<a href=\"http://www.website.com\">website</a> "));
    Text1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

here it will displays your link as *website* in `textview` instead of showing it all.

So I think it's a better approach to make a hyperlink through the last one and it is user-friendly.